# How to Prevent Other User Access based on Authentication and User ID in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, validation, authentication

I have an ongoing Laravel project and I'm currently learning. So there will be multiple users that can register for the system. For example, user1 created an account and made transactions and changes on his account. When user2 register and login, user2 sees everything in user1's account instead of a fresh blank dashboard to get started with. I tried adding `middleware->('auth');` in my routes but it didn't change anything.

HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\MoneyTrade;
use App\MoneyTradeDeposit;
use App\Withdrawal;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Ui\Presets\Vue;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();
    $moneytradeDeposits = MoneyTradeDeposit::all();
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');
    $balance = Withdrawal::sum('amount');

    return view('dashboard', compact('moneytrades', 'moneytradeDeposits', 'amountSum', 'balance'));
}

public function dashboard()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();
    $moneytradeDeposits = MoneyTradeDeposit::all();
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');
    $withdrawal = Withdrawal::all();
    $balance = Withdrawal::sum('amount');


    return view('dashboard', compact('moneytrades', 'moneytradeDeposits', 'amountSum',
    'withdrawal', 'balance'));
}


public function stocks()
{
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');

    return view('home.stocks', compact('amountSum'));
}

public function support()
{
    return view('home.support');
}

public function withdrawal()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();
    $moneytradeDeposits = MoneyTradeDeposit::all();
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');
    $withdrawal = Withdrawal::all();
    $balance = Withdrawal::sum('amount');


    return view('home.withdrawal',  compact('moneytrades', 'moneytradeDeposits', 'amountSum',
    'withdrawal', 'balance'));
}


}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/send-mail', 'SendMailController@send')->middleware('auth');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('register/agreement', 'Auth\RegisterController@show')->name('register.agreement');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('auth');;
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('home.dashboard')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/my-account', 'MyAccountController@index')->name('myaccount.index')->middleware('auth');
Route::patch('/my-account/update', 'MyAccountController@update')->name('myaccount.update')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/stocks', 'HomeController@stocks')->name('home.stocks')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/support', 'HomeController@support')->name('home.support')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/withdrawal-information', 'HomeController@withdrawal')->name('home.withdrawal')->middleware('auth');


Route::resource('withdrawal', 'WithdrawalController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('moneytrade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('moneytrade-deposit', 'MoneyTradeDepositController');
Route::get('/account-removed', 'MoneyTradeController@destroy')->name('mt.delete')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/trading-account', 'MoneyTradeController@view')->name('mt.view')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/trading-account/deposits', 'MoneyTradeController@deposit')->name('mt.deposit')->middleware('auth');
```

How can I achieve this and prevent other users to access other dashboards that's not their own? I don't have roles and just normal users. I just want to prevent one user from accessing other user's dashboard. Thank you!

Comment: `user2 sees everything in user1's account instead of a fresh blank dashboard to get started with` has user1 logged out, also can you give example of some routes which are visible to both users

Comment: Yes, user1 logged out then user2 logged in. However, user2 sees user1's transactions and everything. Basically all the routes should be available for all users. However, not the data of each user from database should be seen. In this example, user1 made deposits and withdrawals on his account which he has access to his own transaction history. What happens is, even when I logout user1 and login user2, user2 can still see all user1's transaction history.

Comment: For your dashboard are you checking whether the details you are sending to your view belongs to the logged in user or not? eg by using Auth()::user() or Auth::id()

Comment: Sorry but where do I check that? What I can verify is when I visit `MyAccount` authentication is it is showing the correct details of the logged in user using Auth::user. How can I check if the details I'm sending to my views are from the logged in user?

Comment: In which table are you keeping your user credentials & how is it connected with your other tables of model MoneyTrade, MoneyTradeDeposit, Withdrawal

Comment: If possible can you show the relationships of all these tables with user table

Comment: The user credentials are in my `users` table. Then I have other tables `money_trades`, `money_trade_deposits` and `withdrawals` tables which are all connected on the `users` table using a foreign key `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`. And I have this something like this ` $moneyTrade->user_id = auth()->id();` on my controllers to save it.

Comment: you just have to so the similar thing, instead of using `all()`, you can put `where()` conditions, eg for your moneytrade in your dashboard function in controller, you are using `$moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();` instead you can use `$moneytrades = MoneyTrade::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();`

Comment: thus it will only get details for logged in user so if user2 logged in the data will not be of user1 in your view

Comment: @bhucho thank you so much for all your help. That works now and very wonderful. Thanks a lot! :)